# trying to submit rails form with trigger/javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form without refreshing the page. I was poking around online, and it seems like something along these lines should work...

```
  <%= form_for(uanswer, :remote => true) do |f| %>

      <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, :class => "radio hide", :onclick =>  
      '$(this.form).submit()' %>
      <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, :class => "radio hide", :onclick =>   
      '$(this).trigger("submit.rails")' %>

  <% end %>
```

yet the page keeps refreshing, and I'm not really sure what's wrong because it seems like this was the solution for many other people's problems as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are including jquery-ujs https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs?

Comment: @iltempo awesome! thanks! My application.js wasn't loading them properly so I just downloaded and included it separately. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stuff depends on the jQuery library and Rails' UJS adapter. Both are installed by default, but must be included when rendering views. Check your layout files for the following lines:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Ensure they are loaded in before the form, or else it won't override the default form behavior (submit/refresh) with Ajax goodness. Check the page source in your browser to make sure those JavaScript files are in fact being included.